# how to insert all this checkbox value into same id but different rows of one column?

Tags: php, checkbox, insert

how to insert all this checkbox value into same id but different rows of one column

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Return" name ="secondtechno[]">Return<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Payment" name ="secondtechno[]">Payment<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Audit" name = "secondtechno[]">Audit<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="Form15CA" name = "secondtechno[]">Form15CA<br>
<input type="checkbox" value = "Form15CB" name = "secondtechno[]">Form15CB<br>
```

Comment: Show me what you've tried and we can have a discussion, might help if you showed us the database schema too

Comment: $chk = "";  
            foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
            {  
             $chk .= $chk1;
              
               
            }

Comment: but data store in same row with , seperate

Comment: Sorry pal but that's not going to cut it, where did $checkbox1 come from? Think to yourself if I saw this question would I be able to give an answer based on what info is infront of me, I think you'll find the answer is NO

Comment: <?php $checkbox1="";    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {               $checkbox1=$_POST['techno'];  
 $chk = "";  
            foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
            {  
             $chk .= $chk1;
              
               
            }              want to store in multiple rows with same id

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in php to check the checked box values using array and try to insert inside foreach with that particular id

```
$id= 'Your_id';
if(!empty($_POST['secondtechno'])) {
    foreach($_POST['secondtechno'] as $check) {
            //echo $check;
            //$sql = "INSERT INTO YourTable(id, columnname)VALUES ('".$id."', '".$check."')";
    }
}
```

Comment: thnkss for help , i use this code but how i write code for when i click on multiple checkbox instead of one then data is inserted in next next row with same id

Comment: ID      SERVICE     
3         payment                   
3         audit       
3         form15ca        
3         form15cb

Comment: it work but it store value as a GSTVAT in services column, what i do for storing GST <br>VAT in different row of that column

Comment: you need to define that GST and VAT in seperate checkbox

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="GST" name ="secondtechno[]">GST<br>
             <input type="checkbox" value="VAT" name = "secondtechno[]">VAT                                       my html code

Comment: but i have problem with database storage

Comment: what is the probem?

Comment: yes i told u before ,the values from checkbox is stored in db column in one row ,i want to store GST in one row , VAT in next row but with same id means only added rows into column when i click on checkbox